# Square is a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I remember, in the geometry class, our teacher used to tell us some definitions or something that i don't really know about.
Why is square a parallelogram?

Comment: Because its opposing sides are parallel.

Comment: See the definition of parallelogram: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parallelogram.html

Answer (score 1):

If you define a parallelogram to have two pairs of parallel sides then a square will satisfy this definition thus all squares are parallelograms. But this does not mean all parallelograms are squares.

Comment: why are not all parallelograms squares?

Comment: @FreeMind Because a square is a specific type of parallelogram just like a banana is a specific type of fruit. A square needs to have right angles which all parallelograms do not have. A banana needs to be yellow and banana shaped, a lot of fruit is not yellow or banana shaped.

Comment: Alright, I wanted to make sure.Anyway, are there any other definitions for other shapes like rectangle and ... ?

Comment: @FreeMind - Yes, there are definitions for other shapes like rectangles. You can find these definitions in a book called a "dictionary".